# C# A simple Hangman game

Tags: c#, project, words

I'm trying to create a simple Hangman game and i have gotten so far, to make it read all words from a text file, but I don't know how to make the code work for every single word. I have another project, working with 3/4 words but with repeating nested if statements. I want to make it as shorter as possible.
This is the code i have so far :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] words = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Letters\Letters.txt");
        int LengthOfArray = words.Length;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int random = rnd.Next(1, 3);
        char[] letters = words[random].ToCharArray();
        bool WordIsHidden = true;
        char hiddenChar = '_';
        char GuessedLetter = hiddenChar;

        var retry = true;
        while (retry = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(letters);
            letters = GuessedLetter.ToString().ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 1; i <= LengthOfArray; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", GuessedLetter);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter!");
            char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (words[random].Contains<char>(letter))
            {
                WordIsHidden = false;
                GuessedLetter = letter;
                Console.Write(letters);
            }
            else
            {
                 if (WordIsHidden == true)
                {
                    Console.Write("You guessed wrong!");

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also I'm trying to make the game show each letter, the user has guessed on it's corresponding position, but now the letter is one line higher than the rest of the word and it's not in it's right position.

Edited:

```
Here is the result :
cat
___Enter a letter!
a
__
aaaEnter a letter!
t
aa
tttEnter a letter!
```

IF anyone have a clue for where does this come from and how can I fix it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm guessing at the problem here but I think you are describing an off by one error here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= LengthOfArray; i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LengthOfArray; i++)
```

As indexing in C# starts at 0. This is probably causing the issue you are seeing. However a foreach loop here would be better as you are not using the value 'i' at all.

```
foreach(var c in words)
  Console.Write(GuessedLetter);
```

as for making the program shorter, don't worry too much right now, get the program working and then refactor later. I'd advice starting with looking into LINQ/IEnumerable extensions, also type inference via the var keyword.

EDIT:

Ok I spent 5 minutes looking over your code, I put in a couple of fixes (see comments). Please review against the original code. It is not a pretty, efficient or elegant solution but hopefully it behaves more inline with what you were expecting.

```
using System;
using System.Linq
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] words = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Letters\Letters.txt");
        int LengthOfArray = words.Length;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int random = rnd.Next(1, 3);
        char[] letters = words[random].ToCharArray();
        bool WordIsHidden = true;
        char hiddenChar = '_';
        //fix 1 use a list or hashset or similar to store the selected chars
        var guessed = new List<char>();
        var retry = true;
        while (retry = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(letters);
            //fix 2, loop over the letters, checking whether they have been guessed
            foreach(var c in letters)
            {
                if (guessed.Contains(c))
                    Console.Write(c);
                else
                    Console.Write("_");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a letter!");
            char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (words[random].Contains<char>(letter))
            {
                WordIsHidden = false;
                guessed.Add(letter);
            }
            else
            {
                if (WordIsHidden == true)
                {
                    guessed.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed wrong!");
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace HangMan.cs.hange_man
    {
        class HangManGame
        {   // checking for word 
            static bool IsWord(string secreword, List<string> letterGuessed) 
            {

                bool word = false;
                // loop through secretword
                for (int i = 0; i < secreword.Length; i++) 
                {
                    // initialize c with the index of secretword[i]
                    string c = Convert.ToString(secreword[i]);
                    // check if c is in list of letters Guess
                    if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
                    {
                        word = true;
                    }
                        /*if c is not in the letters guessed then we dont have the
                         * we dont have the full word*/
                    else 
                    {
                        // change the value of word to false and return false
                        return word = false;

                    }

                }
                return word;
            }

            // check for single letter 
            static string Isletter(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed) 
            {
                // set guessedword as empty string
                string correctletters = "";
                // loop through secret word
                for (int i =0 ; i < secretword.Length; i++)
                {
                    /* initialize c with the value of index i
                     * mean when i = 0
                     * c = secretword[0] is the first index of secretword
                     * c = secretword[1] is the second index of secretword and so on */
                    string c =Convert.ToString( secretword[i]);

                    // if c is in list of lettersGuessed 
                    if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
                    {
                        // add c to correct letters
                        correctletters += c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // else print (__) to show that the letter is not in the secretword
                        correctletters += "_ ";
                    }

                }
                // after looping return all the correct letters found
                return correctletters;

            }

            // The alphabet to use
            static void GetAlphabet(string letters) 
            {
                List <string>  alphabet = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) 
                {
                    char alpha = Convert.ToChar(i+96);
                    alphabet.Add (Convert.ToString(alpha));                
                }

                // for regulating the number of alphabet left
                int num = 49;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.WriteLine("Letters Left are :");

                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    if (letters.Contains(letters))
                    {
                        alphabet.Remove(letters);
                        num -= 1;
                    }
                    Console.Write("["+alphabet[i]+"] ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            /* random strings
            static string RandomWord(string secretword) 
            {
               Random rnd = new Random();

            }*/


            static void Main() 
            {
                Console.Title = ("HangMan");

                // secretWord
                string secretword = "foreground";
                List <string> letterGuessed = new List<string>();


                int live = 5;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman Game");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("Guess for a {0} letter Word ", secretword.Length);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.WriteLine("You have {0} live", live);
                Isletter(secretword,letterGuessed);
                // while live is greater than 0
                while (live > 0 ) 
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();

                    // if letterGuessed contains input



                        if (letterGuessed.Contains(input))
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine("You Entered letter [{0}] already",input);
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                            Console.WriteLine("Try a different word");
                            GetAlphabet(input);
                            continue;                    
                        }                                     


                    // if word found
                    letterGuessed.Add(input);
                    if (IsWord(secretword,letterGuessed)) 
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine(secretword);
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations");
                        break;
                    }
                        // if a letter in word found
                    else if (secretword.Contains(input))
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        Console.WriteLine("wow nice entry");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        string letters = Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
                        Console.Write(letters);

                    }
                        // when a wrong code is entered
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Oops, letter not in my word");
                        live-=1;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} live", live);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    // print secret word 
                    if (live == 0) 
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("Game over \nMy secret Word is [ {0} ]",secretword);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("press any key to Exit");
                Console.ReadKey();




            }
        }
    }
```